# "Транслитерация" или "Транслитерирование"?

Tags: выбор-слов, транслитерация

Объясните пожалуйста, как правильно: "транслитерация" или "транслитерирование"?

Насколько я понимаю, первое слово – существительное (примерно как "бег"), а второе – глагол (примерно как "бежать"). Правильно ли это?

Примеры, которые меня интересуют:

> Транслитерация/транслитерирование осуществляется по стандарту ICAO.
>
> ```
> а a     з z    п p     ч ch
> б b     и i    р r     ш sh
> в v     й i    с s     щ shch
> г g     к k    т t     ъ ie
> д d     л l    у u     ы y
> е e     м m    ф f     э e
> ё e     н n    х kh    ю iu
> ж zh    о o    ц ts    я ia
> ```

> Пример транслитерации/транслитерирования по стандарту ICAO:
>
> Съезжинский переулок → Sieezzhinskii pereulok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

И *траслитерация*, и *транслитерирование* – существительные (отвечают на вопрос *что?*).
Глагол – [*транслитерировать*](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) (*что делать?*).

Я бы порекомендовал использовать первое слово – ***траслитерация***. Оно зафиксировано в [словарях](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/244170), встречается в Национальном корпусе русского языка (36 источников, 49 вхождений), в отличие от второго.
Все запросы по слову ***транслитерирование*** ведут к первому, например:
[транслитерирование](https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&from=ru&to=xx&did=ogegova&stype=) – см. транслитерация. К тому же оно длинное и  "неудобное" в фонетическом плане.